# Element columns association in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the following dataframe and I would like to write a lambda function able to recognise that if an element in col1 is in one of the group in col2 so it take the value col3 associated to that group as in the Result below for col1=(5,6) having the value col3=(0.3,0.2)

```
col1 col2 col3
1 .  1    0.7
2 .  2 .  0.9
3 .  3,5 .0.3
4 .  4,6 .0.2  
5 .  NaN .NaN
6 .  NaN .NaN
```

Result

```
col1 col2 col3
1 .  1    0.7
2 .  2 .  0.9
3 .  3,5 .0.3
4 .  4,6 .0.2  
5 .  NaN .0.3
6 .  NaN .0.2
```

I wrote the lambda function

```
f = lambda x: next(iter([y for y in df['col2'].dropna().tolist() if str(x) in y]), df['col3])
df['col1'].apply(f)
```

But I am not quite sure this the way

Comment: What is the type of `col2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values of `col2` are list, for example:

```
   col1    col2  col3
0     1     [1]   0.1
1     2  [2, 4]   0.2
2     3  [3, 5]   0.3
3     4  [4, 6]   0.2
4     5     NaN   NaN
5     6     NaN   NaN
```

You could do the following:

```
# create lookup dictionary to replace for nan
pairs = df[['col2', 'col3']].explode('col2').dropna()
lookup = {int(key): value for key, value in pairs.itertuples(index=False, name=None)}

# replace the value only where isna
df['col3'] = np.where(df.col3.isna(), df.col1.map(lookup.get), df.col3)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   col1    col2  col3
0     1     [1]   0.1
1     2  [2, 4]   0.2
2     3  [3, 5]   0.3
3     4  [4, 6]   0.2
4     5     NaN   0.3
5     6     NaN   0.2
```

Notice that you must import numpy for this solution to work. If `col2` is a string, you could try:

```
df['col2'] = df.col2.str.split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC method from `explode` and `map`

```
s=df.assign(col2=df.col2.str.split(',')).explode('col2')
df['col3']=df.col1.astype(str).map(s.dropna().set_index('col2').col3).values
df
   col1 col2  col3
0     1    1   0.7
1     2    2   0.9
2     3  3,5   0.3
3     4  4,6   0.2
4     5  NaN   0.3
5     6  NaN   0.2
```

Comment: I have the error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @Annalix explode is after pandas 0.25

Comment: Thanks a lot. Updated pandas version and now it works.